# How To Initiate A Message Request From Content Script On Tab Change?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I've an extension which need to keenly keep an eye on the URL of the very active tab in the browser [chrome]. Currently, I've been able to track those URL's which user load/reload from start. But if there is a tab change, the content script doesn't send message to background script and get back anything.

In fact I want to reload content.js script on tab change of user as well.

Here's what I've done till now:

CONTENT.JS:

```
// Code here....

chrome.extension.sendMessage({ wants: 'URL' }, function(res) {
var urlResponse = res.url;
});

// Code here....
```

Works pretty well, but this content.js doesn't fire on tab change. Instead it fires when a document is changed in same tab (like visiting new link, etc)

BACKGROUND.JS:

```
chrome.extension.onMessage.addListener(
    function(script, sender, sendResponse) {
        if (script.wants == 'URL') {
            sendResponse({ maskedURL: sender.tab.url });
        }
    }
);
```

MANIFEST.JSON:

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,

  "name": "NAME HERE",
  "description": "DESC HERE",
  "version": "1.1",
  "options_page": "options.html",

  "browser_action": {
        "default_title": "NAME",
        "default_icon": "icon.png",
        "default_popup": "popup.html"
  },
  "icons": { "16": "icon.png",
           "48": "icon.png",
          "128": "icon.png" },
  "permissions": [
        "storage",
        "<all_urls>",
        "tabs"
  ],
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["http://*/*","https://*/*"],
      "js": ["content.js"]
    }
  ],
  "web_accessible_resources": [
      "bg.png",
      "*.woff",
      "*.woff2"
  ],
  "background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"]
  }
}
```

Thank you!

EDIT: Xan please have a look:

[image]

Comment: What is the end goal though? I mean, current URL is available to the content script as `location.href`

Comment: `var url = location.href;` is not updated when user switches between 2 tabs so desired actions (like switching icon from active-to-inactive) can't be done

Comment: Not updated where? In the background page?

Comment: No actually, if you could help me to code something which displays alert of active tab's URL, that's what I want. Even on tab switch. I can explain you with an image. Let me update question

Comment: So you want the content script to know that the page became active?

Comment: Please have a look @Xan on image

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/64719/discussion-between-user2513722-and-xan).

Answer (score 1):

Could not understand your question properly but I will try to clarify to the best of my knowledge.

`content.js` is run once when a new page is opened or an existing page is refreshed.It cant access the details of the currently active tab.

If you want to know about any details of the tabs,use `chrome.tabs` API in `background.js`

```
chrome.tabs.onActivated.addListener(activeInfo){ //Fired when an active tab is changed
    chrome.tabs.query({'active':true,'currentWindow':true},function(array_of_tabs){//Gives details of the active tab in the current window.
        alert(array_of_tabs[0].url);
});
```

Comment: I think the OP wanted to run a function in the content script when a tab is activated, see [chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/64719/discussion-between-user2513722-and-xan). Note that your approach is still the right approach: you can send a message from `onActivated` listener to the content script. So, +1 to you.